# Order of unordered_map changes on assignment

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered-map

I'm curious about this behaviour. I found that assigning an `unordered_map` changes the internal order of the unordered map, without any insertion/deletion:

```
unordered_map<int, string> m1;
unordered_map<int, string> m2;
unordered_map<int, string> m3;

m1[2] = "john";
m1[4] = "sarah";
m1[1] = "mark";

m2 = m1;
m3 = m2;

for(auto it = m1.begin(); it != m1.end(); ++it) {
    cout << it->second << " ";
}
cout << endl;
for(auto it = m2.begin(); it != m2.end(); ++it) {
    cout << it->second << " ";
}
cout << endl;
for(auto it = m3.begin(); it != m3.end(); ++it) {
    cout << it->second << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

outputs:

```
mark sarah john 
john sarah mark 
mark sarah john
```

I know that there isn't any specific order maintained on an `unordered_map` due to the fact that internally is a hash table, so an element insertion can end anywhere and a re-hash will mix it all.

However, here the order is changing just after an assignment. I expected the order to be the same, as I thought it would just copy the underlying storage.

The first explanation I thought was that maybe `unordered_map` is taking advantage of the copy to re-hash the new map into a more optimal arrangement. However, I tried to repeat an assignment on a new map (m3) from m2 and the order of m2 is not preserved in m3.

Why does assigning the map change the order?

My compiler is Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)

Comment: I like the part where you recognize that there is no internal order of an *unordered* map.... then still wonder why the order isn't consistent

Comment: @CoryKramer It is a good question, though. The question is why the backing storage isn't copied *as is*; why is it rearranged?

Comment: @Justin and if the answer is simply "the backing storage is implementation defined therefore no one can give you a better answer than random guessing or implementation specific details" what should we do with that information?

Comment: @CoryKramer Yes I understand that's the answer according to the standard. But the OP's question is about *why* it is implemented that way. Even if that's implementation specific details, it is a good question (maybe not a good one for SO, but it's a good question)

Comment: What implementation are you using. [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b14923b68539f03) gives "expected" results

Comment: May be related to this: https://accidentallyquadratic.tumblr.com/post/153545455987/rust-hash-iteration-reinsertion

Comment: Thanks @Justin, I didn't know the answer would be so guessed.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm compiling with "Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)"

Comment: @GonzaloSolera If you add a `m4` add assign `m3` to it does `m4` look like `m2`?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, it looks like m2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an implementation detail of [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx):

> ```
>     _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
>     unordered_map& operator=(const unordered_map& __u)
>     {
> #ifndef _LIBCPP_CXX03_LANG
>         __table_ = __u.__table_;
> #else
>         if (this != &__u) {
>             __table_.clear();
>             __table_.hash_function() = __u.__table_.hash_function();
>             __table_.key_eq() = __u.__table_.key_eq();
>             __table_.max_load_factor() = __u.__table_.max_load_factor();
>             __table_.__copy_assign_alloc(__u.__table_);
>             insert(__u.begin(), __u.end());
>         }
> #endif
>         return *this;
>     }
> ```

<sup>[From libc++'s **unordered_map** header](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/unordered_map)</sup>

If we assume you are using C++11 or greater, then this basically works by clearing the old hashtable, then inserting the elements of `__u` into this vector.

That means that when you do:

```
m2 = m1;
```

It's roughly equivalent to the following code:

```
m2.clear();
m2.max_load_factor(m1.max_load_factor());
m2.insert(m1.begin(), m1.end());
```

This doesn't happen when you use [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc), as its implementation of `operator=` is just `= default` (see libstdc++'s [**unordered_map** header](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/unordered_map.h))

Comment: Trying it on wandbox, my "equivalent code" isn't quite equivalent: https://wandbox.org/permlink/byubQ9VEU9UPCcsf . That may just be a different version of *libc++*, or a different standard library altogether

Answer (score 2):

Since obviously this is implementation-specific (it is an *unordered* map after all) I'm going to make an educated speculation.

If `mark` and `john` have the same hash and collide for the number of buckets in question, and the implementation uses chaining we may be able to explain this. If the chaining implementation inserts new items at the front (constant time even for a single-linked list) then every time you assign the container the chained-item order will be swapped.

Comment: I feel like it's rather unlikely that `mark` and `john` would have the same hash, and if so, the problem should go away by using different strings, which doesn't seem to be the case (e.g. https://wandbox.org/permlink/hFVcM6fuLAG72rzx). Granted, the different strings may collide as well, but it shouldn't be hard to find strings which don't collide.